# C# DragEnter event of the Winforms DragDrop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

Why do we actually need to handle DragEnter event of the drop destination?

What is its effect at the destination?

### At Source

```
public partial class ToolBoxForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public ToolBoxForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void lbl_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)sender;
            lbl.DoDragDrop(lbl.Image, DragDropEffects.Link);
        }
    }
```

### At Destination:

```
public partial class DrawingArea : Form
    {
        public DrawingArea()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DrawingArea_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolBoxForm toolBoxForm = new ToolBoxForm();
            this.AddOwnedForm(toolBoxForm);
            toolBoxForm.Show();

            pictureBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        }

        private void picDrawingArea_DragEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;                
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }

        private void picDrawingArea_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawImage((Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), new Point(e.X - this.Left - 12, e.Y - this.Top - 30));
        }
    }
```

When I am commenting out the code:

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
                {
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;                
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
                }
```

The image is not being dropped.

Comment: Seems the OP seeks exact explanation for what happens in the 'DragEnter event, whether or not it must be defined, and Effect property set, for Drop to work.

'DragEnter and 'DragDrop get an EventArgs of type 'DragEventArgs : so one could, theoretically, set a DragEventArgs param Effect property in the Drop call to a DragDropEffects enumeration value.

The consensus seems to be that defining DragEnter, and setting the Effect to something other than None is required : but so far answers have been "disclaimered" by "I believe," "I think.," etc. 

So, imho, the question remains unanswered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From to the [`DragDropEffects` MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dragdropeffects.aspx):

> **Member
>
>     name**     **Description**
>   None     The drop target does not accept the data.
>   Copy     The data from the drag source is copied to the drop target.
>   Move     The data from the drag source is moved to the drop target.
>   Link      The data from the drag source is linked to the drop target.
>   Scroll     The target can be scrolled while dragging to locate a drop position that is not currently visible in the target.
>   All       The combination of the Copy, Move, and Scroll effects.

So you've got to set it something other than `None` if you want to accept the drop.

However, the next quote led me to believe that it was just used for feedback:

> You can use **DragDropEffects** to display different mouse pointers for drag-and-drop operations. For example, you can display a plus symbol for a **Copy** drag-and-drop operation, an arrow symbol for a **Move** drag-and-drop operation, or a red circle with a line through it symbol for a **None** drag-and-drop operation.

Comment: But when I am commenting out the code, the image is not being dropped on the drop area. Plz, see the update.

Comment: I believe if you don't switch away from DragDropEffects.None, you can't handle the drop event.  This means you have to switch it to something like DragDropEffects.Copy if you want to know when the user drops what they were dragging.  Could be wrong...

Comment: If I call e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) and don't change the cursor, then the image is not being dropped on the drop area. That is, same problem.

Comment: And I have created another VS2005 sln. I am dragging a node from treeview to a DataGridView. The same problem is happening if i do not handle this event. I think, this is essential in all cases. Have you come up with your own test?

Comment: If you set e.Effect to None, you are telling the D+D plumbing that you don't accept the drop.  The default is None so commenting out your code disables the drop.

Answer (score 1):

I really think the Drop event won't fire if DragDropEvents is left at None (which is the default).  So that's why the image doesn't drop.